# groupby columns containing lists

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

My pandas data frame looks the following:

```
title               genre                rating
Shutter Island      [Horror, Action]     8
Spectre             [Action, Thriller]   7
```

I would like to group by genre and find the mean rating.
The problem is that the genre column contains lists (of variable length). I just want to add a movie to a group if the genre appears in the list of genres.

I know so far that as lists are mutable I can do something like

```
movies['genre']=movies['genre'].apply(tuple)
movies.groupby(['genre']).mean()
```

But of course that is not what I want, because I way too many groups. As this may help, the set of all possible genres is

```
{'Action',
 'Adventure',
 'Animation',
 'Comedy',
 'Crime',
 'Documentary',
 'Drama',
 'Family',
 'Fantasy',
 'Foreign',
 'History',
 'Horror',
 'Music',
 'Mystery',
 'Romance',
 'Science Fiction',
 'TV Movie',
 'Thriller',
 'War',
 'Western'}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to flatten lists and then is possible aggregate `mean`:

```
from itertools import chain

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'genre' : list(chain.from_iterable(movies['genre'].values.tolist())), 
    'rating' : movies['rating'].values.repeat(movies['genre'].str.len())
})

print (df)
      genre  rating
0    Horror       8
1    Action       8
2    Action       7
3  Thriller       7

df = df.groupby('genre', as_index=False)['rating'].mean()
print (df)
      genre  rating
0    Action     7.5
1    Horror     8.0
2  Thriller     7.0
```